# Xamarin forms: SwipeGestureRecognizer also enable MasterDetailPage Navigation Drawer?

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation-drawer, master-detail, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have implemented the swiping feature using `SwipeGestureRecognizer` on my homepage. But the problem is the home page is a child of a `MasterDetailPage`. So when I swipe to left in the homepage, the navigation drawer is also coming to UI. I have tried like below to stop showing navigation drawer on UI when doing `SwipeGestureRecognizer` using `MessagingCenter`, but no luck!!!

**On Homepage**

```
public void Swipe(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessagingCenter.Send<HomePage>(this, "HomePageSwipe");
    //code for swipe
}
```

**On MasterDetailPage Constructor**

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<HomePage1>(this, "HomePageSwipe", (sender) =>
{
    IsPresented = false;
    NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
});
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this behavior occurs only on ios. To disable this, you need to add this to the OnAppearing() method

```
if (Xamarin.Forms.Device.RuntimePlatform == Xamarin.Forms.Device.iOS)
{
    IsGestureEnabled = false;
}
```